# Getting a . instead of a / in my link(path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
# GET system_accounts/:id
  def show 
    # If a system account already exists in session, it was found from a search with the account id
    # Otherwise, this is a new search for a system account by the given id
    if params[:id]
      Rails.logger.debug { "Querying for the account with id: #{params[:id]}" }
      response = query_account(CGI.escape(params[:id]))
    if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        @account = JSON.parse(response.body)
    unless @account.empty?
      redirect_to system_accounts_path(params[:id])        
    end 
    end
```

The above is my show action. So the thing is if i search with my id=2 i should get the resultant link to be system_accounts/2 but what i get is system_accounts.2 . why a . instead of a / . Anything i am missing out on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are closely following the rails convention, you should use `system_account_path(params[:id])` (without an `s`). 2 is interpreted as the format so it is appending `.2` to the url because `system_accounts_path` most probably points to the index action of system_accounts controller. remove the s to point to the show action.